# ViewModel is not getting called first time in master details page in Xamarin forms with prism

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Master details page in my application. I have used Prism in my application.

First time my details page view model is not getting called and due to this page is showing as empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InforConcierge.Views" 
            x:Class="InforConcierge.Views.MainPage">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:LeftMenuPage x:Name="masterPage" Icon="home.png"/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage x:Name="NavPage" BarBackgroundColor="{DynamicResource appColor}"  > 
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

In master page i have "Home","Contacts" options.

**Note:** If I switch to another menu item("Contacts") and the select "Home" in menu page, then my view model of Home page is getting called.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to this page through code? will the viewmodel initialise then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly creating an `HomePage` object from XAML. As far as I know, Prism is not able to intercept this and hence no viewmodel is created. You'll have to navigate to the page in order to enable Prism to auto-resolve the VM. We are loading our main view by calling

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MenuViewWrapper/NavigationRootPage/HomePage");
```

from `App.OnInitialized`. *Please note* that `MenuViewWrapper` (which would be your `MainPage`) and `NavigationRootPage` (which can be replaced by `NavigationPage` in your example)  have to be registered for navigation ([see here](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html)).

Comment: Yes with this ViewModel is getting called. 

In Homepage I am showing a progress bar till my list is loaded, but in iOS progress bar is not showing. 

Below is the code i am using to show

 UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading();

If I switch to another menu item and come back to Homepage, progress bar is showing, Only the issue is first time it is not loading progress bar in iOS.

Comment: Above is fixed, it was due to ViewModel name